# Spring boot and Postgres: Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am getting the following error when I start my spring boot application using `docker-compose up:`

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

**Application properties:**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/employeeapp
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

**Docker-compose file:**

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    network_mode: bridge
    container_name: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    expose:
      - 5432
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=employeeapp
    restart: unless-stopped
  # APP*****************************************
  springbootapp:
    image: springbootapp:latest
    network_mode: bridge
    container_name: springbootapp
    expose:
      - 8080
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    links:
      - postgres
volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

**Docker file for application:**

```
FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk
COPY target/employeeapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar employeeapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/employeeapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

What is the issue here? From various [guides](https://studygyaan.com/spring-boot/how-to-connect-postgresql-database-in-spring-boot-project?utm_content=cmp-true) I have followed I seem to have configured the application correctly?

I am able to pull an image of `postgres` separately and run the container and connect to it using `dbeaver`.

However it seems my `spring boot` app is unable to connect to the `postgres` image being created in the docker-compose file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking to another container, not localhost.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/employeeapp
```

should be

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/employeeapp
```

It is also easier to call the container something like `db`:

```
services:
  db:
```

And reference it by it's function:

```
depends_on:
  - db
```

and name:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/employeeapp
```

Comment: when I make these changes I get: | org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" . Assume I do not need to have the postgres container running before I do docker compose?

Comment: docker-compose starts both the "springbootapp" and "db" applications i.e. PostgreSQL, it also stops them together. Now that you are connecting, you have to figure out your password problem.